# Como aceder a dados de um Hashmap noutra classe

Tags: java, hashmap

Como posso aceder a dados de um `Hashmap` noutra classe?

Exemplo:

Classe1:

```
Hashmap<String,String> teste = new Hashmap<>();
teste.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
```

Classe2:

Como posso ter acesso ao `Hashmap` teste?

Ao instanciar a `Classe1` o `HashMap` não fica com os dados ou fica?

Comment: Oi. Não vejo o conteúdo da Classe2?

Comment: Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Nos ajude ajudar você.

Comment: Não coloquei nada no conteúdo da Classe2 porque simplesmente gostava de saber o que tenho de por lá, para poder utilizar os valores do HashMap da classe1 ! Terei de criar um método na Classe1 que devolva o HashMap e depois adicioná-lo a um novo HashMap criado na Classe2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disponibilizando o mapa

Primeiramente, é necessário definir algum meio de recuperar o mapa que está na `Classe1`. Há várias formas de fazer isso...

### 1. Atributo de instância

O mapa poderia ser colocar em um atributo de instância, com os valores inicializados no construtor:

```java
public class Classe1 {
    public Map<String, String> teste = new Hashmap<>();
    public Classe1() {
        teste.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
    }
}
```

### 2. Método que retorna o mapa da instância

Porém, não é recomendado ter atributos públicos. Isso quebra o encapsulamento da classe. Então poderíamos ter um método *getter*:

```java
public class Classe1 {
    private Map<String, String> teste = new Hashmap<>();
    public Classe1() {
        teste.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
    }
    public Map<String, String> getMapa() {
        return teste;
    }
}
```

### 3. Método que retorna um novo mapa

Se houver necessidade de criar vários mapas diferentes, dependendo de alguma situação, crie o mapa em um método e retorno-o:

```java
public class Classe1 {
    public Map<String, String> getNovoMapa()
        Map<String, String> teste = new Hashmap<>();
        teste.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
        return teste;
    }
}
```

## Disponibilizando o mapa *estaticamente*

Se o conteúdo do mapa não for dependente de uma instância da `Classe1`, por exemplo se os valores forem fixos, então ele não precisa depender de uma instância da `Classe1`.

Também há várias formas de fazer isso:

### 1. Atributo estático

O mapa poderia ser colocar em um atributo estático, com os valores inicializados num bloco de inicialização estático:

```java
public class Classe1 {
    public static Map<String, String> testeEstatico = new Hashmap<>();
    static {
        testeEstatico.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
    }
}
```

### 2. Método estático que retorno o mapa da classe

Porém, temos no exemplo anterior o problema com o encapsulamento da classe. Então poderíamos ter um método *getter* estático:

```java
public class Classe1 {
    private Map<String, String> testeEstatico = new Hashmap<>();
    static {
        testeEstatico.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
    }
    public static Map<String, String> getMapaEstatico() {
        return testeEstatico;
    }
}
```

### 3. Método estático que retorna um novo mapa

Para retornar um novo mapa estaticamente:

```java
public class Classe1 {
    public static Map<String, String> getNovoMapaEstatico()
        Map<String, String> testeEstatico = new Hashmap<>();
        testeEstatico.put("TESTE", "exemplo");
        return testeEstatico;
    }
}
```

## Acessando o mapa

Se o mapa não é estático, a `Classe2` precisa ter uma referência a uma instância da `Classe1`.

Isso pode ser feito de várias formas...

### 1. Instanciando a `Classe1` diretamente

```java
public class Classe2 {
    public void metodo() {
        Classe1 classe1 = new Classe1();

        //recupera novo mapa
        Map<String, String> testeNovo = classe1.getNovoMapa();

        //recupera mapa da instância através do getter
        Map<String, String> teste = classe1.getMapa();

        //recupera mapa diretamente do atributo da instância (não recomendado)
        Map<String, String> teste2 = classe1.teste;
    }
}
```

### 2. Recebendo uma instância da `Classe1` por parâmetro no método

```java
public class Classe2 {
    public void metodo(Classe1 classe1) {
        //recupera novo mapa
        Map<String, String> testeNovo = classe1.getNovoMapa();

        //recupera mapa da instância através do getter
        Map<String, String> teste = classe1.getMapa();

        //recupera mapa diretamente do atributo da instância (não recomendado)
        Map<String, String> teste2 = classe1.teste;
    }
}
```

### 3. Tendo uma instância da `Classe1` dentro da `Classe2`

Nesse caso, o atributo `classe1` deve ser inicializado de alguma forma.

```java
public class Classe2 {

    Classe1 classe1;

    //inicialização via construtor
    public Classe2(Classe1 classe1) {
        this.classe1 = classe1;
    }

    //inicialização via setter
    public void setClasse1(Classe1 classe1) {
        this.classe1 = classe1;
    }

    public void metodo() {
        //recupera novo mapa
        Map<String, String> testeNovo = classe1.getNovoMapa();

        //recupera mapa da instância através do getter
        Map<String, String> teste = classe1.getMapa();

        //recupera mapa diretamente do atributo da instância (não recomendado)
        Map<String, String> teste2 = classe1.teste;
    }
}
```

## Acessando o mapa estaticamente

Caso o mapa seja estático, é possível acessá-lo diretamente de qualquer ponto do código.

```java
public class Classe2 {
    public void metodo() {
        //recupera novo mapa
        Map<String, String> testeNovo = Classe1.getNovoMapaEstatico();

        //recupera mapa da classe através do getter
        Map<String, String> teste = Classe1.getMapaEstatico();

        //recupera mapa diretamente do atributo da classe (não recomendado)
        Map<String, String> teste2 = Classe1.testeEstatico;
    }
}
```

## Considerações

Há vantagens e desvantagens nas várias abordagens. Em resumo:

- Evite acessar atributos diretamente
- Para mapas "constantes" (que não mudam), use métodos estáticos que retornam um atributo estático
- Quando há relação de dependência entre duas classes, evite usar `new` diretamente, prefira sempre receber a instância via construtor ou *setter*. Esse é o conceito de Inversão de Controle, que diminui o acoplamento entre as classes, facilita a criação de testes unitários e ajuda no entendimento do código, pois deixa a dependência explícita.

Comment: Muito boa explicação, desde já o meu sincero obrigado, consegui resolver o meu problema :)